# keyDown does not work on IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, protractor, keydown

browser: IE10

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform();
```

This action does not work on IE10, but works well on chrome and firefox. Please help to check. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @loanburger I don't think he's binding a handler, I think this is Protractor code for triggering it.

Comment: @Barmar  Yes, I never bind a handler, I just want to select two elements with the CONTROL key pressed. But this cannot be done on IE10.